# Как из интервала дат убрать все выходные и праздничные дни

Tags: sql, sql-server

Всем привет. Задача такая:

1. Есть дата начала задачи и дата окончания задачи (например: 5 дней). Необходимо найти сколько дней выполнялась задача. Назовем это интервал. (это я нашел)
2. Есть таблица с производственным календарем. Которая состоит из "Дата" и "Статус". Статус: 0 это выходной или праздничный день, 1 это рабочий день.

**Вопрос:** Как найти сколько дней выполнялась задача при условии, что все выходные и праздничные дни в этом интервале будут учтены. Т.е. с момента даты начала задачи до момента окончания задачи прошло 5 дней, но задача была взята в пятницу. По простой разнице дат получается, что дата выполнилась за 5 дней, но по факту она выполнилась за 3 дня, т.к. суббота и воскресенье не будет учитываться.

Прошу прощения, что не написал, как я решаю, но пока даже идей нет. Есть только как я считаю интервал между датами: `iif(datediff(day,[ДатаНачала], [ДатаОкончания]) = 0, 1, datediff(day,[ДатаНачала], [ДатаОкончания]))`

**upd:** Добавил данные из БД, вот из примера видно, что интервал между двумя датами 7 дней, но по факту, там есть 2 дня выходных, поэтому интервал будет 5.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Это скрин из таблицы производственного графика, где видно, что 19 и 20 числа нерабочий день (0х00)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `join` по датам и `where calendar.status = 1`

Comment: @MaxDown, join по датам можно, но если даты окончания и начала не попадают в выходные дни, а вот даты между этими датами попадают, то как тут тогда это сделать?

Comment: Не понятен вопрос в комментарии. Лучше приведите исходные данные, верные и неверные

Comment: @MaxDown дополнил вопрос, думаю так будет понятней. Получается надо, чтобы вместо 7 дней было 5.

Comment: вам надо в запросе исключить все выходные и праздничные дни, для этого сделайте условие NOT EXISTS (select [выходной] from [календарь выходных] where [выходной] = [таблица графика].[дата]) названия таблиц и полей условные, проставьте свои. Календарь выходных должен быть заполнен датами.

Comment: JOIN и особенно EXISTS - это из пушки по воробьям. Присмотритесь к ответу Германа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если исходить из того, что в производственном календаре есть все интересующие дни, по одной строке на каждый, то нам нужно найти количество дней (строк) в производственном календаре, которые, во-первых, попадают в интервал между датой начала и датой окончания включительно, во-вторых, являются рабочими.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [производственный календарь] AS C
WHERE C.[Дата] BETWEEN [ДатаНачала] AND [ДатаОкончания]
  AND C.[Статус] = 1
```

Comment: Чувствуется рука мастера) я бы ещё >=/<= на BETWEEN заменил